# Files through map function in map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

Is it possible to somehow pass a set of files through each map function. The requirement will be to process each file in parallel for different-2 operations. I am completely new to map reduce and i am using JAVA as my programming language.

Comment: If you want to get the same file as input to all mappers, for read only access, yes.  You can add your files from your main (Driver) class to what is called `Distributed Cache`. More details can be found here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the same file as input to all mappers, for read only access, yes. You can add your files from your main (Driver) class to what is called Distributed Cache. More details can be found [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html).